# Would Harry Potter Wizards use the Internet?

Tags: harry-potter, technology, muggles

The Internet has a lot to offer that you cannot send by owls, like sub-second latency of messages. Same things for computers and technology in general. Since Harry Potter seems to take place in the early 21st century, Internet should have been rolling out to the public during the first 7 books.

Would it make sense for witches and wizards to use computers, the Internet, or other advanced muggle technology?

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Internet

Comment: [Sure, they had a setup wizard at hogwarts](http://thesetupwizard.tumblr.com/tagged/setupwizard/chrono)

Comment: The answer below, with direct canon quotes addressing this question, would seem to suggest that it's *not* primarily opinion-based.

Comment: That's a well researched answer. Also, the question doesn't deserve all the downvotes.

Comment: The books were actually set in the mid-90s when internet usage was much less common (if not unheard of).

Comment: You've obviously never read RFC1149. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149/. 
 And yes, it has been implemented

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, but only out of curiosity

Wizards do not need the internet, but they will occasionally use it out of curiosity or when researching about Muggles.

> When you can summon any book, instrument or animal with a wave of the wand and the word Accio!; when you can communicate with friends and acquaintances by means of owl, fire, Patronus, Howler, enchanted objects such as coins, or Apparate to visit them in person; when your newspaper has moving pictures and everyday objects sometimes talk to you, then the internet does not seem a particularly exciting place. **This is not to say that you will never find a witch or wizard surfing the net; merely that they will generally be doing so out of slightly condescending curiosity, or else doing research in the field of Muggle Studies.**
>
> <sub>[Pottermore: Technology](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/technology)</sub>

Harry himself has never used the internet.

> **Has Harry ever used the Internet?**
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *No. He's not allowed near Dudley's computer and Dudley's the only one who's got a computer. He gets beaten up if he goes too near the keyboard. So no, he's never used the Internet. I use it a lot but not Harry. Wizards don't really need to use the Internet but that's something that you'll find out later on in the series. They have a means of finding out what goes on in the outside world that I think is more fun than the Internet. Could anything be more fun than the Internet? Yes!*
>
> <sub>[Raincoast Books interview transcript, Raincoast Books (Canada), March 2001.](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-raincoast-interview.html)</sub>